# Images in UITableView grow and shrink when device is changing orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, orientation

I'm encountering what I find to be a strange quirk in my app...

I have a UITableView with several sections and rows in each section. At the far right of each header is a green + to tap to add a new row below. At the far right of each row is a pencil button to tap to edit the row. Works beautifully.

When I rotate the device, however, the pencil button temporarily grows to about 3x its size and shrinks as it takes up its new location at the edge of the screen. This happens both during a change to landscape and to portrait. I've included photos to show you but its hard to get a screen shot during rotation... This is NOT happening to the green + buttons, though.

The code for my UITableView is below too. It's long and convoluted - sorry. Just hoping someone could point out why this is happening. Thanks!

normal pencil
[image]

[inflated pencil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TzpD.png)
[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {    
    return 0.00001
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 35
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {    
    let headerBar = UITableViewHeaderFooterView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tablePrayer.frame.width, height: 35))

    let hLabel = UILabel()
    hLabel.text = prayerListSectionNames[section].uppercaseString
    hLabel.frame = CGRectMake(25, 0, headerBar.frame.width - 35, 35)
    hLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)
    hLabel.textAlignment = .Left    
    headerBar.addSubview(hLabel)

    let headerButton = UIButton()

    let imgX = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"red white x.png"))
    imgX.frame = CGRectMake(2, 10, 15, 15)
    imgX.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    let imgP = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"green plus.png"))
    imgP.frame = CGRectMake(2,10,15,15)
    imgP.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    showPrayerListSection = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("showPrayerListSection") as! Array
    var arrow = UIImage(named: "exp clps arrow right.png")

    if showPrayerListSection[section] {    
        arrow = UIImage(named: "exp clps arrow down.png")!
    }

    let imgExpand = UIImageView(image: arrow)
    imgExpand.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 10, 35)
    imgExpand.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    headerBar.addSubview(imgExpand)

    headerButton.frame = CGRectMake(tablePrayer.frame.width - 30, 0, 20, 35)
    headerButton.tag = 20000 + section

    if movingRows {
        headerButton.addSubview(imgX)
        headerButton.addTarget(self, action: "deleteButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    } else {
        headerButton.addSubview(imgP)
        headerButton.addTarget(self, action: "addButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }
    headerBar.addSubview(headerButton)

    let toggleShowButton = UIButton()
    toggleShowButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tablePrayer.frame.width - 50, 35)
    toggleShowButton.addTarget(self, action: "toggleShowPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    toggleShowButton.tag = 30000 + section
    headerBar.addSubview(toggleShowButton)
return headerBar
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {    
    var numberOfSections = 0

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("prayerListSectionNames") != nil {    
        prayerListSectionNames = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("prayerListSectionNames") as! Array
        numberOfSections = prayerListSectionNames.count
    }

    return numberOfSections
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {    
    var rowsInSection = 0
    var tempNames = [String]()

    showPrayerListSection = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("showPrayerListSection") as! Array

    if showPrayerListSection[section] {
        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(prayerListSectionNames[section]) != nil {  
            tempNames = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(prayerListSectionNames[section]) as! Array
            rowsInSection = tempNames.count
        }
    }

    return rowsInSection
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    var sectionItems = [String]()

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(prayerListSectionNames[indexPath.section]) != nil {
        sectionItems = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(prayerListSectionNames[indexPath.section]) as! Array
    }

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "prayerCell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = sectionItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

    let imgPencil = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "pencil.png"))
    imgPencil.frame = CGRectMake(7, 0, 20, cell.frame.height)
    imgPencil.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    imgPencil.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    let pencilButton = UIButton()

    let dbX = tableView.frame.width - 35
    pencilButton.frame = CGRectMake(dbX, 0, 30, cell.frame.height)
    pencilButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight

    if !movingRows {
        pencilButton.addSubview(imgPencil)
    }

    pencilButton.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    pencilButton.titleLabel!.text = "\(indexPath.section)"
    pencilButton.tag = 100000 + indexPath.row
    pencilButton.addTarget(self, action: "pencilButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    cell.addSubview(pencilButton)

    return cell 
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    tablePrayer.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I will suggest you to use autolayout instead of using static frames

Answer (score 0):

It's because you dynamically assign the width of the button. You take the width of the screen - 35px. When the screen rotates the width of the screen changes so does you button.

You should check if your screen is portrait or landscape, based on that you should give appropriate values for the button width and height.

Comment: I can see that but I am wondering why it would cause a photo to change size when I don't have any constraints set for that photo. In theory, unless I call the table to reload, it shouldn't resize at all... (Which I do after the device has rotated) Or am I overlooking something?